# How to open latest downloaded file

Tags: java, jsp, pdf, download

I have a jsp form with a download button.Whenever user clicks that button it will download a pdf file and popups that.I'm using chrome browser. My download location is

```
C:\Users\gt\Downloads
```

For this I have used the following code to open from that location.

```
String filePath=System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\Downloads\\"+pdfname;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " +filePath);
```

Now when user clicks the download button the pdf file will get save in that location by the name like `F90CR0010-HBR-C-4.pdf` and my code will open this correctly.

When the user clicks the download button again for second time it will save as like `F90CR0010-HBR-C-4 (1).pdf` But my code will open the old previous file only.Because the name is that only.I need to open the latest downloaded file.

Any Idea of how to open the latest downloaded file??I have a idea that I can add the current time to my `pdfname` and so it will be unique.But my requirement is that pdf name should be like this only.

Comment: What happens if the user changes the default file name? IE if I save it as test.pdf, will it still open? In other words, how do you create the value for the variable pdfname?

Comment: User is not going to change the name of pdf. In IE everytime it asks for open save like that.But in chrome I dont see anything like that.Anyways user wants the pdf to pop up after download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what the base file name would be (in your case `F90CR0010-HBR-C-4.pdf` ) then you can use a simple regex to check for strings of the form `F90CR0010-HBR-C-4\(\d+\).pdf` . If you find one then just figure out which one has the biggest number and open that one.

Its not really pretty, but it works. Also, technically this can be "hacked" by making your own file called F90CR0010-HBR-C-4(999999).pdf, but I would guess you dont really care.

Comment: The base file name need not to be that always.But it will in that format.My regex pattern for the filename is like `[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9]CR[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]`

Comment: So how should I define variable `d` here?

Comment: No - \d is a regex character class. Its basically a shortcut for [0-9]. Find more info [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).